# Combine 2 arrays of hashes into one JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a site that has a kind of newsfeed function. I want to pull data from a table with items and data from a table with users then combine parts of that data into a JSON response. Both are arrays of hashes. I don't though want to take all of those fields, only parts.

I was thinking I would pull both full records then do the combining in a method so as to only hit the DB twice. I can easily pull the last 5 items with:

```
class NewsfeedsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @newsfeed_data = json_response(return_items(params[:limit]))
  end

  private

  def return_items(limit)
    output = Item.last(limit=limit).reverse
  end
end
```

Now I'm stuck. I don't know how to remove the unwanted items from output or how to combine it with the user data. Item belongs to User in the model so there's a user_id field linking them.

Here are the schemas for Items and Users

```
create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.text     "description"
  t.string   "type"
  t.json     "properties"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",                   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                   null: false
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_items_on_user_id", using: :btree
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  [lots of Devise settings...]
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
  t.string   "company"
  t.string   "position"
  t.string   "email"
  t.json     "tokens"
  t.datetime "created_at",                               null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                               null: false
  t.string   "avatar"
  [indexes...]
end
```

Here would be my desired output:

```
{
  "name": "Item name",
  "type": "Item type",
  "first_name": "User owner's first name",
  "company": "User's company",
  "avatar": "URL string to saved image"
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what you'd like the JSON response to look like? Also, if you mention a `Item` model , but in your example you put `Deal`. If you could include some more details about the models this concerns that would make it easier to help :)

Comment: Sorry, was copying over code from another project. I added the schemas for what each record has in it and the output I'm hoping to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest and most maintainable way to do this would be to use the `ActiveRecordSerializers` gem.

1. [Install the gem](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/v0.10.6)
2. Create a file at `app/serializers/newsfeeds_serializer.rb`
3. In that file, define a serializer that looks like this:

   ```
   class NewsfeedsSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
     attributes :name, :type, :first_name, :company, :avatar

     def first_name
       object.user.first_name
     end

     def company
       object.user.company
     end

     def avatar
       object.user.avatar
     end
   end
   ```
4. In your controller, write your index route as follows:

   ```
   class NewsfeedsController < ApplicationController
     before_action :authenticate_user!

     def index
       @items = Item
         .order(created_at: :desc)
         .limit(params[:limit])
         .includes(:user)
       render json: @items, each_serializer: NewsfeedsSerializer
     end
   end
   ```

This will serialize each `Item` object using the methods we defined in the serializer. Using [:includes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) will preload the `User` items that each `Item` belongs to, so everything we'll use gets grabbed in one database call.

If you ever want to edit to the JSON you're sending, it's easy to make changes to the serializer. I suggest reading through the ActiveModelSerializer [guides they provide](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/v0.10.6/docs/README.md) if you run into any problems getting set up or you want more custom config (`camelCased` keys or something like that).

Comment: Excellent, thank you! This expands really well in my case for the next series of response I need to write.

Comment: I got this working, with just a couple of edits, if you wanted to update your answer. I had to call `each_serializer: NewsfeedSerializer` in the last call and I needed to include the methods defined as attributes, so the entire line reads `attributes :name, :type, :first_name, :company, :avatar`. Works awesome, though. Thanks for introducing me to this gem.

Comment: @oneWorkingHeadphone made the changes, glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this but probably rails has something already built for extracting JSON responses.

```
def return_items(limit=10)
    items = Item.includes(:user).select('user_id, name, type, etc_you_want_to_pick').first(limit)
    response = []
    items.each do |item|
      response << {
        "name": item.name,
        "type": item.type,
        "first_name": item.user.first_name,
        "company": item.user.company,
        "avatar": item.user.avatar
      }
    end
    return response
  end
```

Probably if you are fine with having the whole user in the hash you could use the same AR query and then just call .as_json on the collection.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Since I'm going to be expanding the response I send for other actions I think I'm going to go with the serializer option, but if it was a one off I would definitely prefer this to adding another gem.